# How to insert "--SELECT--" into combo box after binding data from data table in winform using c#

Tags: sql-server, c#-3.0

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT  DISTINCT [DEPUTED BU] FROM [sheet1$] where [DEPUTED BU] is NOT NULL", oledbConn);
OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
oleda.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
oleda.Fill(ds, "Employees");
DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Employees"];
oledbConn.Open();
CombTBu.DataSource = dt;
CombTBu.DisplayMember = "DEPUTED BU";
CombTBu.ValueMember = "DEPUTED BU";
oledbConn.Close();
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
CombTBu.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

//i am able to add an empty row.but how to populate data into added new row???
can u plz help me???

Answer (score 0):

```
OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT  DISTINCT [DEPUTED BU] FROM [sheet1$]", oledbConn);
OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
oleda.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
oleda.Fill(ds, "Employees");
DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Employees"];
oledbConn.Open();
CombTBu.DataSource = dt;
CombTBu.DisplayMember = "DEPUTED BU";
CombTBu.ValueMember = "DEPUTED BU";
DataRow drNewRow = dt.NewRow();
drNewRow["DEPUTED BU"] = "--Select--";
dt.Rows.InsertAt(drNewRow, 0);
CombTBu.SelectedIndex = 0;
oledbConn.Close();
```

Comment: I got the output.Try this code to add "--select--"after binding data to combobox from data table